# Neovim not showing neither virtual text nor signs for lsp diagnostics

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol

I want to have inline virtual text and signs showing errors, warnings, etc. I already had it working before in previous configurations that used Packer, but now, using Lazy.nvim, it doesn't work. I've tried the LunarVim and NvChad distributions and, using the same compiled neovim binary, both work. LunarVim uses Packer and NvChad uses Lazy.nvim. I never had to do anything to get it working before.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/marcosdly/dec9a37ed96a8d16aba99e2f8c27423e) (gists) are my plugins, completion and lsp config files. The files' formatting and conventions don't match because I'm just trying to get it running before organizing everything evenly.

I tried:

- adding a `textDocument/publishDiagnostics` handler;
- testing with different language servers;
- trying different configurations that use the same plugins (LunarVim, NvChad);
- searching through lsp handlers and diagnostics documentation;
- searching google and stackoverflow for similar issues and tutorials.